# nativeType(<"Alt+F4>") / close window

Tags: python, squish

I am using a windows application. I am trying to close floating windows using nativeType("") in squish. This works for closing the 1st window, but when I reuse the nativeType again for another window of same type, it closes the whole application instead of closing the window.

The floating window is an image window which has no object id and its name keeps changing every time I acquire an image. I have to close the window in order to get to next step, but sometimes it closes the whole application.

what is the best way to close floating window with no proper ID in squish?

Comment: `nativeType` sends the keyboard input to whatever control has the keyboard focus (if any), so if you find that it does the wrong thing it may well be that a different control should have the focus.

Answer (score 0):

you have to set a hookup to the window that you want to close.
E.G. you want to close Chrome:

```
Chrome_Context1 = startApplication("Chrome")
verifyChrome1 = setApplicationContext(Chrome_Context)
nativeType("<Alt + F4>")
```

If you don't set a hookup on a window you can't close it with the nativeType() command

Comment: I forgot that this is written in python and you should check the commands currentApplicationContext(), defaultApplicationContext() or setApplicationContext()